# Why can't my bulk loadable CSV file be opened?

Tags: sql-server, sql, bulk

This is my error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened.
>
> Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.)

I've checked permissions and everything seems fine. The auto bulk insert flow has been working up until yesterday where the same code base started to toss this exception from the sql level. SQL uses a UNC path to another application box to get at the file that we want to bulk insert.

The file path SQL will use is something like `\\myserver\csv\Application\Bulk\file.csv`

Just looking for suggestions as to what the issue might be or what I can do to remedy.

This has been up and running on our production servers for some time now and it's just yesterday that this popped up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) on both boxes, filter the status column to only show `ACCESS DENIED` events and then you can inspect the properties of the event to see who doesn't have access to what file.

Comment: which is the status column? you mean operation? and are we sure the operation will be called ACCESS DENIED?

Comment: it looks like it's the result column, man. thanks. something to try.

Comment: @towps: Sorry for the wrong column name, mistakes happen. If an error reports that the OS says that access is denied for a file then it's most likely to be ACCESS DENIED. There are other results like INVALID OPERATION but when I have permission or access problems it's almost always ACCESS DENIED, as the others more likely result in other things like crashes...

Comment: if anyone needs more info on this issue or some possible suggestions, this article may help [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jay_akhawri/archive/2009/02/16/resolving-operating-system-error-code-5-with-bulk-insert-a-different-perspective.aspx)